# SQL executing setting wrong column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following sql statement and when writing to the `SourceMembers` table, the `guid` column is having the string 'guid' written to every column.
Is this the syntax below doing this or is the problem coming from the temp table `SourceMembers`?

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Groups].[dbo].[%1Members] OFF 

INSERT INTO SOURCEMEMBERS 
            ([GROUPID], 
             [GUID]) 
SELECT CONVERT(INT, GROUPID), 
       'guid' 
FROM   [#SOURCEMEMBERS]
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `guid`.

Comment: Why not the square bracket that you have been using all throughout your query so that it would become `[guid]` instead of `'guid'`?

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: I am going to guess that you have a column named "guid" that is defined as varchar but holds the value for a uniqueidentifier. You should use the proper datatypes instead of converting everything to strings.

Comment: Jesus, i can't believe how stupid I am!!!! You know when you don't want to do something and can't get your mind right on it!

Answer (score 0):

You have put guid in single quotes which assumes it to be a string constant. Instead you want to fetch guid column, hence remove single quotes around guid.

Run this

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Groups].[dbo].[%1Members] OFF 
INSERT INTO SourceMembers ([GroupID],[guid]) 
SELECT CONVERT(INT, GroupID),guid FROM [#SourceMembers]
```